# Cannot register new CQ query on Apache Geode

Tags: gemfire, geode

I stuck in place while trying to register cq query with ClientCache. Still getting this exception:

```
CqService is not available.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CqService is not available.
at org.apache.geode.cache.query.internal.cq.MissingCqService.start(MissingCqService.java:171)
at org.apache.geode.cache.query.internal.DefaultQueryService.getCqService(DefaultQueryService.java:777)
at org.apache.geode.cache.query.internal.DefaultQueryService.newCq(DefaultQueryService.java:486)
```

The client cache is created as follow:

```
def client(): ClientCache = new ClientCacheFactory()
.setPdxPersistent(true)
.setPdxSerializer(new ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer(false, "org.geode.importer.domain.FooBar"))
.addPoolLocator(ConfigProvider.locator.host, ConfigProvider.locator.port)
.setPoolSubscriptionEnabled(true)
.create()
```

and suggested [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563332/unable-to-create-continuous-query-on-geode) does not help. Actual library version is:

```
  "org.apache.geode" % "geode-core" % "1.0.0-incubating"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pull in `geode-cq` as a dependency. In gradle

```
compile 'org.apache.geode:geode-cq:1.0.0-incubating'
```

Comment: Thanks for anwser, it seems to be reasonable decision to put in in other module. However, I've just switched to Event Handlers and it works as expected without additional dependencies.